# Jsoup - Prevent adding closing tags

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I have to handle some not valid HTML files and have to add attributes to some tags and need the starting and end positions of the tags. So using the xml parser is not an option, because the position information get lost.

Is there any possibility to prevent jsoup from repairing "broken" HTML and don't add additional tags?

Example:

```
<b><p><font>Some Text</b>Text</font></p>
```

Output from JSOUP is:

```
<b></b><p><b><font added=attribute>Some Text</font></b><font>Text</font></p>
```

But I want:

```
<b><p><font added=attribute>Some Text</b>Text</font></p>
```

Comment: Can you update the code also ? what you tried so that easy to sorted out?

Comment: Your "b", "p" and "font" sections are overlapping. I don't think it's doable, and it's certainly a bad idea. The result you want is not valid HTML. HTML sections need to be nested, not overlapping. `<p><font added=attribute><b>Some Text</b>Text</font></p>` would be valid HTML, with the result you want, I think.

Comment: And what's wrong with the output you get with JSoup, actually?

Comment: Sorry for answering late :/ you are hundred percent right, this is just malformed HTML is not valid at all. I worked around the problem by loading the HTML file with JSOUP then save them. And after that I added the attributes to the tags.